# Android: create image button with programmatically drawn shape as its image

Tags: android

I'd like to programmatically create a button with a custom drawn shape as the image. In my activity's onCreate, I have:

```
final FrameLayout contentContainer = new FrameLayout(this);
final FrameLayout.LayoutParams contentLayoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
contentContainer.setLayoutParams(contentLayoutParams);
contentContainer.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

int size = 50;

final ShapeDrawable drawable = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
drawable.getPaint().setColor(Color.RED);
drawable.setBounds(0, 0, size, size);

final ImageButton leftArrow = new ImageButton(this);
leftArrow.setImageDrawable(drawable);
final FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(size, size);
leftArrow.setLayoutParams(lp);
contentContainer.addView(leftArrow);
```

When I run the app, I see a blue screen with a plain white button. I has hoping to see a red oval on the button, but it seems I'm not understanding the setImageDrawable call.

Any suggestions how to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you try to set the drawable as the background of the button instead of the image, with setBackgroundDrawable?

Comment: yeah, that looks like it works - thanks! If you wanna make it an answer, I think then I can accept it...